# Using Python's win32com to send a MSMQ message that requests an answer via a response queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, response, msmq, pywin32

I'm trying to convert Microsoft's Visual Basic / C++ example code to Python 3. It sends a MSMQ Message which requests a response in a response queue.

The example is here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms705720(v=vs.85).aspx

```
import win32com.client
import os

computer_name = os.getenv('COMPUTERNAME')

strdestformatname = "direct=os:" + computer_name + "\\PRIVATE$\\python_in"
strrespformatname = "direct=os:" + computer_name + "\\PRIVATE$\\python_out"

dest_msmq = win32com.client.Dispatch("MSMQ.MSMQDestination")
resp_msmq = win32com.client.Dispatch("MSMQ.MSMQDestination")

dest_msmq.FormatName = strdestformatname
resp_msmq.FormatName = strdestformatname

msg = win32com.client.Dispatch("MSMQ.MSMQMessage")

# This next line creates
# Member not found
# pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Mitglied nicht gefunden.', None, None)
msg.ResponseDestination = resp_msmq

msg.Label = "Test Message: Response"
msg.Send(DestinationQueue = dest_msmq)
```

I have created a "python_in" and "python_out" MSMQ queue on my computer.
These work. If I remove the line:

```
msg.ResponseDestination = resp_msmq
```

the message appears in the "python_in" queue.
I cand also send it directly to the "python_out" queue.

The error message is

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Mitglied nicht gefunden.', None, None
(=Member not found)

Below is an image showing how the message arrives when commenting out the reply queue code. Without a reply queue, of course.

[image: This is how the queued message looks. It has no reply queue]

Some additional info:
I'm testing this on Win7 professional with 32bit Python 3.6.5 and the latest pywin32 (version 223) installed.

Info on how to do MSMQ without reply is here:
http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/sending-msmq-messages-python.html

Someone claims he got a similar thing to work (setting a response for
acknowledgement), here, with source:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21207798/Python-and-MSMQ.html

I also got this to run in IronPython a few years ago, but that one is Python 2
[How to create a new MSMQ message in IronPython with label, reply queue and other properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815850/how-to-create-a-new-msmq-message-in-ironpython-with-label-reply-queue-and-other)